# Jersey 2.23.2 + Spring 4.3.4 + Spring data JPA 1.10.5

Tags: spring, jersey, spring-data-jpa

We are developing a project currently using Jersey 1.18 ,Spring 3.1.0 and Spring data jpa 1.2.0.We are trying to migrate to Jersey 2.23.2 + Spring 4.3.4 + Spring data JPA 1.10.5,but we are getting lots of exception.we resolve one and another comes and so on....It looks to be issue with compatibilities of versions of jars.
If somebody has worked with similar versions of Jersey + Spring + Spring data jpa and can share list of jars(with versions),it would be great help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you not using maven?

Comment: @peeskllet -Thanks for your response.Yes ,I am using Maven.

Comment: @peeskllet  - Any suggestion pls.

Comment: I have an older [github project](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-spring-example/blob/master/pom.xml) that uses this stack. The versions are slightly older. Try changing the versions to suite your needs. If it fails, let me know, and I'll check it out a bit later when I have time

Comment: I just pushed a commit to the project with updated dependency versions (same as you are requested). It works fine.

Comment: @peeskillet -Thank you so much.I will try and update you.

Comment: @peeskillet- I add all the dependencies as you suggested....I deployed application(ear) on webshpere liberty...getting following error:                       SRVE0276E: Error while initializing Servlet [jersey-serlvet]: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0200E: Servlet [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer]: Could not find required class - org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer

Comment: I can't really do anything for you for any errors I can't reproduce. I told you that the app I linked to works fine. You can run it yourself. Though it sounds like to me your jars aren't getting deployed with the ear

Comment: I found that somehow jersey-container-servlet and jersey-container-servlet-core ,both were added to the build path and then same was available in deployment assembly,so probably "ServletContainer" was present in both of these  jars and exception was coming.Changed "jersey-container-servlet" to jersey-container-servlet-core,now I am not getting above exception,but it is throwing this exception :Failed to instantiate[org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException

Comment: Again, I don't think I can help you from here with errors I cannot reproduce

Comment: ok np..Can you please tell: 1) If using Xml configuration with Spring 4 works well without any extra configuration. 2) Is it fine to use jersey-container-servlet-core instead of jersey-container-servlet with web-module 3.0.

Comment: I can tell you this, having core and "non-core" together is not a problem. The do not have conflicting classes. "non-core" builds on top of core. And to answer you question, it shouldn't matter. Why don't you play around with my example and find it for sure. Just deploy it with the jetty plugin mentioned in the readme. His way you can find out if errors are due to your deployment method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132346/discussion-between-user2603985-and-peeskillet).